# Ambigous column in field list when join table codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to join two tables and show the data with ajax, codeigniter, and active record, but suddenly shows an error:

> Column 'userfile' in field list is ambiguous

Table structure:

Album: id_album, judul_album, userfile, userfile_type

Photo: id_photo, id_album, judul_photo, userfile, userfile_type

**Controller**:

```
public function ajax_list()
{
  $list = $this->Photo_model->get_datatables();
  $data = array();
  $no = $_POST['start'];

  foreach ($list as $data_foto) 
  {
    $no++;
    $row = array();
    $row[] = '<p style="text-align: center">'.$no.'</p>';
    $row[] = '<p style="text-align: left">'.$data_foto->judul_foto.'</p>';
    $row[] = '<p style="text-align: left">'.$data_foto->id_album.'</p>';
    $row[] = '<p style="text-align: center"><img src="'.base_url('assets/images/photo/').$data_foto->userfile.$data_foto->userfile_type.'" width="100px"></p>';

    $row[] = "
    <p style='text-align: center'>
    <a class='btn btn-sm btn-warning' href='".base_url('admin/photo/update/').$data_foto->id_photo."' title='Edit'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> EDIT</a>
  </p>
  <p style='text-align: center'>
    <a class='btn btn-sm btn-danger' href='".base_url('admin/photo/delete/').$data_foto->id_photo."', onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i> DELETE</a>
  </p>";

  $data[] = $row;
}

$output = array(
          "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
          "recordsTotal" => $this->Photo_model->count_all(),
          "recordsFiltered" => $this->Photo_model->count_filtered(),
          "data" => $data
          );
//output to json format
echo json_encode($output);
}
```

**Model**:

```
public function get_datatables()
{
  $this->_get_datatables_query();
  if($_POST['length'] != -1)
  $this->db->select('id_foto,judul_foto,foto_seo,ket,userfile as ufile,userfile_type as ufile_type');
  $this->db->join('album ', 'album.id_album = foto.id_photo');

  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->result();
}
```

Any help will be so appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which table you want to get the columns from where the columns have the same name. EG. `album.id_album` and `photo.id_album`. So you select should look like this

```
$this->db->select('id_foto,judul_foto,foto_seo,ket,[album|photo].userfile as ufile,[album|photo].userfile_type as ufile_type');
```

Replacing `[album|photo]` with whichever table you need the column to come from. If you need it from both then the below would work

```
$this->db->select('id_foto,judul_foto,foto_seo,ket,album.userfile as album_ufile,album.userfile_type as album_ufile_type,photo.userfile as photo_ufile,photo.userfile_type as photo_ufile_type');
```

Comment: with a little modification, it works. thank you so much sir @shaun

Comment: What was the modification and I'll update the answer?

Comment: something weird, i try to add new record, the query that succesfully show the data: $this->db->select('id_foto, judul_foto,foto.time_upload as time,album.id_album as id_album, album.judul_album as judul_album, foto.userfile as photo_ufile, foto.userfile_type as photo_ufile_type');
but, total data and data which show in datatable is incorrect, in datatable only show 2 datas from 3. what's wrong?

Comment: datatables said: Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries. but in the table only show 2 data

Answer (score 0):

You should use `table_name`.`column name` to solve ambiguous problem.

Try this way:

```
public function get_datatables()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    if ($_POST['length'] != -1) {
        $this->db->select('id_foto, judul_foto, foto_seo,ket, album.userfile as ufile, album.userfile_type as ufile_type');
    }

    $this->db->join('album ', 'album.id_album = foto.id_photo');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
 }
```

Comment: best way to select columns by making alias. example: `table_name`.`column name` AS `alias`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone, finally it solved with:

```
$this->db->select('id_foto, judul_foto, judul_album, foto.uploader as uploaders,foto.userfile as ufile,foto.userfile_type as ufile_type');
$this->db->join('album ', 'album.id_album = foto.id_album');
```